# Need to check the inbox of an Exchange server with C++

Tags: c++, powershell, exchange-server, imap

I'm working on a project in C++ to backup and restore email on Microsoft Exchange servers, I'm trying to write automated tests for the restore function. Right now I can create test users, databases, and mailboxes, and can send email between users through the Exchange Admin Powershell. However, Exchange doesn't have commandlets to view or delete emails (as far as I can tell). Is there a way to do that with straight Exchange commandlets?

I haven't found a way, so instead I'm looking for an IMAP API that I can add to the project to enable viewing and deleting emails. Free would be ideal, but it can't be licensed with GPL. Is there an IMAP API for C++ that doesn't have GPL? Is there an avenue to programatically view and delete emails I haven't tried yet?

EDIT: Honestly I'm not too fussy on how it gets done, I just need a way to do it. I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459253(v=exchg.150).aspx

Search-Mailbox can delete messages.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee633455(v=exchg.150).aspx

ExportMailboxRequest and ImportMailboxRequest cmdlets do most of the heavy lifting for importing and exporting data.

Why do you need to read messages?  Powershell can also do client side scripts using Outlook library commands.

### EDIT

Put a 'magic phrase' in your test email.  "MagicRainbowUnicorn".

1. Delete a message

   ```
   Search-Mailbox -Identity "TestMailbox" -SearchQuery 'MagicRainbowUnicorn' -DeleteContent
   ```
2. Test for message

   ```
   Switch ((Search-Mailbox -Identity "TestMailbox" -SearchQuery 'MagicRainbowUnicorn').count) {
       0 { "No Results Found" }
       1 { "One Result" }
       default { "More than One, or some other strange Result" }
       }
   ```

Comment: I'm trying to automate some tests of the backup and restore functions, so the test should create a test mailbox, send it an email, backup the mailbox, delete the email, restore the email from the backup, then check if the email is there and make sure it matches the original. I can create the mailbox and send it an email, but I haven't figured out how to  delete the email or check if it's there after the restore.

Comment: For verifying it, use `Search-Mailbox` and a magic string in the email.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff459253(v=exchg.150).aspx has an example `Get-Mailbox | Search-Mailbox -SearchQuery 'election OR candidate OR vote' -TargetMailbox "Discovery Search Mailbox" -TargetFolder "AllMailboxes-Election" -LogLevel Full`

For deleting items, they show an example `Search-Mailbox -Identity "April Stewart" -SearchQuery 'Subject:"Your bank statement"' -DeleteContent`

Comment: The Exchange Powershell is telling me it doesn't recognize "Search-Mailbox". I triple-checked the spelling, and other Exchange cmdlets still work. Am I missing something?

Comment: Scratch that. It seems I need to give my Admin account permission to do data importing and exporting.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but could you consume [Exchange Web Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204119%28v=exchg.140%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with C++? I wrote a few programs in C# that use EWS for monitoring mailboxes. I had the ability to view and delete messages from Exchange.

[Edit]
This is a sample of what I used in C#, if you decide to use that instead of C++. Or maybe it'll help steer you in a good direction.

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

ExchangeService svc = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
svc.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user@domain.com", "password");
svc.AutodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com");

// loop through messages in Inbox
foreach (EmailMessage msg in svc.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new ItemView(int.MaxValue)))
{
    // do stuff with message
}
```

Comment: It looks promising, but I haven't been able to find any C++ code examples. Switching to C# is not an option (for reasons). Do you know of any C++ examples or guides?

Comment: The little bit I read surrounding EWS and C++ involved [using Windows Web Services API to create a SOAP request](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/adf2a58c-32b7-477a-adcc-f2d053e2902b/wwsapi-with-ews?forum=wwsapi).

Comment: I looked into it, but roping all that in is way more complicated than it needs to be for the project. And it turns out that there's an Exchange cmdlet I missed that more-or-less does what I need.